# $.ajax load another file if a string is not found in the first

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to load an HTML file, search for a string inside, and if it isn't found, load another file and repeat the process (total about 5-6 files).

Here's my process to further illustrate:

1. Load *file1.html*
2. Search for a string
3. If found, tell user (and end the process)
4. If not found, move to next file and repeat step 1 with *file2.html*

I've been trying to wrap my head around jQuery Deferred objects for the AJAX calls. In simple terms what I've come up with so far is to resolve a main deferred object (`mainDef`) if the string is found - this would presumably stop the script from loading the second file as there is no need.

Otherwise (i.e. if the string is not found in the first file), it would load the second file. And then the third, and so on.

Here's my code:

```
// var $q = string to be searched
// resolved when answer found
var mainDef = $.Deferred();
// resolved when not found in one day
var dayDef = $.Deferred();

$.ajaxSetup({
    success: function(data) {
        var $result = $(data).find("td:contains('"+ $q +"')");
        if ($result.length !== 0) {
            mainDef.resolve();
            return data;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    dataType: 'html',
});

function one() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'one.html'
    });
}

function two() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'two.html'
    });
}

$.when( one(), two() ).then(
    // success
    function(data) {
        var $result = $(data).find("td:contains('"+ $q +"')");
        // found it
        if ($result.length !== 0) {
            $success.removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else {
            $error.removeClass('hidden');
        }
    },
    // fail
    function () {
        alert("Promise failed");
    }
);
```

The problem is, I'm unable to stop the second AJAX request from going through, and that muddles things up for me, because in the `$.when()`/`.then()` block, the success callback isn't getting the response text (in the variable `data`.

I'm not quite sure if this is more of a conceptual question I have or a technical one. I realize I need to be running 2 levels of deferred objects, maybe. If the string is found, it would resolve the main level and exit the script, and if not found it would resolve the 'lower level' deferred while continuing the main level.

So my question is: how do I search for a string in an AJAX'd file, and if not found, load another file?

Comment: Instead of banging my head against this, I've decided to get around the issue for this project by combining the files so that it needs to load just a single HTML file - I would still like to know if my original intention is possible though, so if anyone knows I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could answer your question : build a custom deferred, check the files one by one, mark the deferred as solved if the condition is met, mark the deferred as rejected if all files have failed.

```
var urls=["one.html","two.html","three.html"];

function Finder(urls) {
    var dfd=jQuery.Deferred();

    function fetchUrl(url) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: url
        });
    }

    function parseMatch(res) {
        // that would be the actual parsing
        // a bit of randomness instead
        return (Math.round(Math.random())) ? true:false;
    }

    function getMatch() {
        if (dfd.state()!=="pending") //problem already solved
            return;
        if (urls.length==0) { // no more url to check
            dfd.reject(); // we did not find a match
            return;
        }

        // let's try the next url
        fetchUrl(urls.shift()).
            pipe(parseMatch,getMatch). // and filter the result
            done(function(found) { //file loaded and parsed
                if (found)
                    dfd.resolve();
                else
                    getMatch();
            });
    }
    getMatch();
    return dfd.promise();
}

var f=Finder(urls);
f.done( function() {console.log("found")} );
f.fail( function() {console.log("not found")} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RnhfG/

Comment: This is simply awesome! Works exactly as intended. I feel like I'd been hovering around the concept but couldn't figure out how to actually do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[.pipe()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) is your friend:

```
function testData(data) {
    return $(data).find( "td:contains('"+ $q +"')" ).length
        ? data
        : $.Deferred().reject( $q + " not found" );
}

function find( urls ) {
    return $.ajax( urls[ 0 ] )
        .pipe( testData )
        .pipe( null, urls.length > 1 && function() {
            return find( urls.slice( 1 ) );
        }); 
} 

find( [ "one.html", "two.html", "three.html" ] ).done(function() {
    // FOUND
}).fail(function() {
    // NOT FOUND
});
```